# MVC Editor Template for Decimal and Integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried to create a simple custom editor template for Decimal and Integer types:

```
@ModelType Decimal?
@Html.NumericBoxFor(Function(m) m)
```

and

```
@ModelType Integer?
@Html.NumericBoxFor(Function(m) m)
```

Saved them as ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Decimal.vbhtml and ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Integer.vbhtml (also tried Int32.vbhtml).

However my custom HtmlHelper function is never getting called. After searching the web and trying many things can't figure out.. What's wrong here?

Comment: I just found that in the application was a custom ViewEngine in place which screwed up paths (defined via global.asax). Removing it solves the issue.

Comment: Can you post your comment as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found that in the application was a custom ViewEngine in place which screwed up paths (defined via global.asax). Removing it solves the issue.